# how can we execute .sql script containing views and stored procedure using spring and hibernte

Tags: spring, hibernate

I want to execute my script file(.sql) from the path specified which contains
views and  stored procedure using spring and hibernate

Answer (score 0):

In Spring boot, You can put schema.sql and data.sql into resources/ . It create table or some thing like this and put data.sql it add data into your database. Spring boot automatic create and put data to your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
ITransaction trans = this.GetSession().BeginTransaction();
IDbCommand command = this.GetSession().Connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = sql;
command.Transaction = trans; 
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
trans.Commit();
```